# how to pass data into method while binding them

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

i really want to pass some data to a method that i'm also binding it, something like:

```
<MyComponenet
    onPress={this.logUser('blabla').bind(this)}
>
```

but as you know it gives me `Cannot read property 'bind' of undefine`

What is that

Answer (score 0):

oh got it, it should be like this

```
<Button
     onPress={this.logUser.bind(this, 'sina :)')}
  >
```

just leave this question on the stack in case others have the same question